# I do not get the results from a API-url when clicking submit

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

Needed to be able to add a name into the textbox that will transfer it into the id, so that when the id goes to the API website, it will be able to return(1-3) different versions of that name.

Here is my javascript to do the app commands

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
const bodyParser  = require('body-parser');

const { response } = require('express');


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true}));

app.use(bodyParser.json());

// set the view engine to ejs
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// index page 
app.get('/', function(req, res) {

    res.render('pages/index'); {
    };
});

app.post('/', function(req, res) {
    
    res.render('pages/index'); {
    };
});

app.listen(8080);
console.log('8080 is the magic port')
```

Then trying to connect to my index.ejs. However I do not get the results when I click submit.

(Im pretty sure it is a small mistake but I keep getting back on where I started.)
Below is my ejs file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<!--Need our pretty head-->
<head>
    <%- include('../partials/head'); %>
</head>
<body class="container">

    <!--Need to make sure the header will be display-->
    <header>
        <%- include('../partials/header'); %>
    </header>
    <!--The input for the hero search-->
    <label>ENTER SUPER HERO: </label> 
    <input id="num1"  name="HN" placeholder="name"> <!--HN = HeroNames--> 
    <!--Search Button being functionable & displayed on the website-->
    <button onclick=ff() id="num1" value="Search">Search</button>
    
    <label>I have displays working but when you press "Search". No results will display</label>
    <!--result for the lists of names-->
    
    <div id = "num1">
        <h4>Alter Egos Result</h4> <!--Have the max of 3 results of the HeroName(s)-->
        <li id = "ego1"></li>
        <li id = "ego2"></li>
        <li id = "ego3"></li> <!--Was trying to display pictures as well, but was not able to get it to fucntion properly-->
    </div>
   
    <script>
        //Reloading purpose using querySelector along with window.location.reload 
        document.querySelector('num1').addEventListener('click',() => {
            window.location.reload(true); 
        })

        function ff() {
            //getting element by id of input field text 
            var str = document.getElementById('num1').value;
            //To double the API search used 'fetch'
            fetch(`https://www.superheroapi.com/api.php/103909388781088/search/${str}`)
            //response = json
        .then((response) =>{
        console.log(response)
        return response.json();
             //used to close the first part of the function. response
        //using the data to display
        //function ff();
        
        })
        
        .then((data) => { id = 'num1'
            //Now using the elements from the alter ego.
            const result = document.getElementById("ego1");
            const result2 = document.getElementById("ego2");
            const result3 = document.getElementById("ego3");
            result = [result, result2, result3];

            
            for(var l= 0; l <= data.result.length; l++) {  
                var names = []

                
                
                names.push(data.result[l].biography['full-name'])
                
                result[l].append(names)
                return data.json()
                //return data.json()
            
                }//Close the loop
            }) //close the 2nd part of the function. data display
        //To find any error.
        .catch(err => console.log(error));
        
        
    }
    </script>

    <!--Need are pretty footer displayed-->
    <footer>
        <%- include('../partials/footer'); %>
    </footer>

</body> 
</html>
```

We are given a head, header, and footer already. It is the transaction between the two is getting to me. Which is causing me to keep making mistakes.

Comment: Probably not an answer to your question but I think you should surround function with quotes, like this: `onclick="ff()" `

Comment: I've tried that but still no work. I thank you still for your help.